# iOS Xcode 9: UIView.hidden must be viewed form main thread only

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

[Getting this error from Xcode during runtime.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERnpd.png)

The app does not crash but it does not execute my method.

This is the method where the error message shows up. It gets called by my implementation of the [renderer didAdd method from ARSCNViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate/2865794-renderer)

```
func showLabel(label: UILabel)
{
    label.isHidden = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        label.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that `label.isHidden = false` (and by extension `showLabel:`) is not called in the main thread (your method doesn't have to, but `isHidden` does...). Also, the fact that you get the runtime warning means that your method _does_ get executed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the line you invoked the method is not on main thread, the line `label.isHidden = false` is spitting out runtime warning.

Try this,

```
func showLabel(label: UILabel) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        label.isHidden = false;
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            label.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```